# How to implement gRPC gateway mux handler to handle multiple http methods

Tags: go, http, gorilla, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

I have REST HTTP handlers implemented with [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux). I am trying to migrate them into gRPC. There are some handlers doing file upload and download. So, my client decided to implement those handlers in gRPC gateway.

One of my mux handler handles multiple HTTP methods and do stuffs according to HTTP method in one handler func. Example code is like below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc(`/doSomething`, func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        switch request.Method {
        case http.MethodPost:
            // create something
            fmt.Fprint(writer, "POST")
        case http.MethodGet:
            // return something
            fmt.Fprint(writer, "GET")
        case http.MethodPut:
            // update something
            fmt.Fprint(writer, "PUT")
        case http.MethodDelete:
            // delete something
            fmt.Fprint(writer, "DELETE")

        }
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(`:5000`, r)
}
```

When I implemented similar grpc gateway mux handler to handle those requests with [grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2.3.0](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/tree/v2.3.0), I have to write separate handler functions to handle different HTTP methods to same path. Example code like below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    grpcGatewayHandler := runtime.NewServeMux()
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(grpcGatewayHandler)
    _ = grpcGatewayHandler.HandlePath(`POST`, `/doSomething`,
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
            fmt.Fprint(w, "POST")
    })
    _ = grpcGatewayHandler.HandlePath(`PUT`, `/doSomething`,
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
            fmt.Fprint(w, "PUT")
        })
    _ = grpcGatewayHandler.HandlePath(`GET`, `/doSomething`,
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
            fmt.Fprint(w, "GET")
        })
    _ = grpcGatewayHandler.HandlePath(`DELETE`, `/doSomething`,
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
            fmt.Fprint(w, "DELETE")
        })
    http.ListenAndServe(`:5000`, r)
}
```

I couldn't find any alternative solution to use different methods in same handler func.

1. Is there any way to handle different methods in one handler with
   grpc-gateway?
2. Is there no difference between handling methods separately and
   in one handler func?

Answer (score 0):

your proto file going to be like this

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/api/httpbody.proto";


service SampleService {
  rpc doSomethingPost (Request) returns (google.api.HttpBody) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/doSomething"
    };
  }

  rpc doSomethingPUT (Request) returns (google.api.HttpBody) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      put: "/doSomething"
    };
  }

  rpc doSomethingGet (Request) returns (google.api.HttpBody) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/doSomething"
    };
  }

}
```